# How to delete the settings while uninstalling the extension in the Magento

Tags: magento

Can anybody tell me that how can i remove all the settings associated to the extension from the database tables. Like if i am uninstalling the abc extension than the value abc_setup will also be deleted from the core_resource table. Similarly other setting from the core_config_data table too. And also delete the database tables too. Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do that manually in the database (or sometimes via a script which is provided by the plugin author).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove your extension using magento connect. It will remove all associated tables from DB. No settings are saved.  And  your extension is not  EAV type then you can delete that file manually with tables.

Answer (score 0):

Some extension add EAV related row in eav_attribute table so you need to check its setup folder for this and if that has been added you need to delete it manually.
Also one entry of version goes into core config table that too needs to be removed.
Module moght also created tables specific for its own feature looking at its setup folder sql code will give you idea on that.

Plus you need to remove complete module folder and >xml that was added to etc/modules  folder.